# Swift. Авторизация в вконтакте

Tags: vkontakte-api, swift

Не нашел нормальной документации по авторизация в Вконтакте на Swift. Только Object C. Может кто-нибудь объяснить step-by-step как это делается? Swift только начал познавать. После авторизации хочу получить страницу с фото авторизованного, ФИО и тому подобную информацию из профиля.

Comment: покажите как этот код выглядит на objC, вам добрые люди переведут

Comment: Описание как это делается на Object C тут: https://vk.com/dev/ios_sdk

Comment: Сам исходник здесь: https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-ios-sdk